# Understanding Slutky's Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Slutky's theorem:  Let $\{X_n,A_n\}$ be random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^p$ a vector of constants. If $X_n\rightarrow^d X$ and $A_n \rightarrow^p a$ then $A_n^tX_n\rightarrow^d a^tX$.

I'm reading a proof that goes as follows:

(1) Let $f$ be continuous and bounded. If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E(f(X_n))=E(f(X))$ then $X_n\rightarrow^d X$. Note that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E(f(X_n))=E(f(X))$ is only true when f is bounded and Lipschitz, then $X_n\rightarrow^d X$.

(2) Let $f$ be bounded and Lipschitz. Then $|E(f(A^t_n))-E(f(a^tX)|\leq |E(f(A^tX_n)) - E(f(a^tX_n))| + |E(f(a^tX_n)) - E(f(a^tX))|\rightarrow 0$ if $x\rightarrow f(a^t x)$

I have two questions regarding this proof.

**(1)** How does the second condition works? The "is only true" bothers me. Why  $X_n\rightarrow^d X$ if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E(f(X_n))=E(f(X))$ **is only true when f is bounded and Lipschitz**.

**(2)** Is it possible to assume that such function $f$ exists in this condition? Why is the limit zero? I see that $|E(f(a^tX_n)) - E(f(a^tX))|\rightarrow 0$ follows from $X_n\rightarrow^d X$, but I can't see how $|E(f(A^tX_n)) - E(f(a^tX_n))|\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Can you give a link or reference to exactly what you're reading?  Your paraphrase doesn't quite make sense to me and I'd like to see the original.

Comment: @NateEldredge My apologies. I would post the original but I'm not sure if my native language is comprehensible to all. I tried to rephrase it to make it more clear. Please do let me know.

Comment: Is it possible that what (1) really says is the following: "If $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[f(X_n)] = E[f(X)]$ for all bounded Lipschitz functions $f$, then $X_n \to^d X$"?  That is a true statement.  But the "only true" part doesn't make any sense.  If that's not the issue, I would encourage you to post the original in whatever language, since I think this is more likely a case of misreading or mistranslation.